# sqlsrv_connect: Login failed for user

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012

I am testing out my new installation of 5.3:

```
<?php

$serverName = "ks252";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ocustom");

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Unable to connect.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. ) )
```

what does this mean>? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: as you are not providing a username, it appears to be trying to login as the user the webserver/application is running as, and that user doesn't have permission.  Either grant that user permission, or provide a username/password to login.

Comment: @Doon i am following this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2012/03/12/what-sql-server-2012-means-for-php-developers.aspx which i thought was for win authentication?

Comment: @doon the user that is opening that PHP code has full access on the database, could you give me an example of how to connect using username/pass?

Comment: Why don't you try using the PDO Connection library/drivers for MSSQL? I'm currently working with that; it's easier than `sqlsrv_*` functions.

Comment: @user1968541 thank you for the suggestion, can you show me how i can get started and tell me why you think it is easier?

Comment: You should take a look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167.aspx it gives the various connection options for sqlsrv_ and PDO

Comment: This is my preference anyway. Since i've been using PDO for a long period of time, i've grown acustomed to it. It's flexible in terms of database connections. With a switch, you can connect from a MySQL database to a MSSQL database. View this link for the required Drivers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php   then skimover the manual for PDO :http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Are you trying to get the code to run as the user visiting the webpage, so that they access the DB with their own permissions?  If so, you will need to set the web server up to impersonate the user, otherwise the server will try and access the DB using the username specified in the application pool identity.

Comment: @steoleary thanks so much! how do i impersonate?

Comment: If you look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) there is a section on how to enable impersonation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting php to MS SQL Server. Login failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779487/connecting-php-to-ms-sql-server-login-failed)