# Connecting php to MS SQL Server. Login failed

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my sql server database, but i keep getting this message:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 
[code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 
[code] => 4060[2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Store" requested by the login. The login failed. 
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Store" requested by the login. The login failed. )
 [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. 
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 
[code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Store" requested by the login. The login failed.
 [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Store" requested by the login. The login failed. ) )
```

I don't even understand what is that NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user.
It's running on Apache.

UPD: Forgot to add the code

```
<?php
$servername="(local)";
$connection=array("Database"=>"Store");
$link = sqlsrv_connect($servername,$connection);
if( $link )
{
     echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

UPD2:
Problem solved. As always right at the moment I tried to use some help.
Thank you for explaining what the NT Authority\System user is. 
Changed the user, that's running apache to the one, that's used for sqlserver and it works.

Comment: NT Authority\System is what is running apache. its the windows system account.

Comment: There's a problem with the credentials you're using to connect to the database - could you add that code to your question, please? Once you've removed all the actual login information, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this resolves: http://security.fnal.gov/cookbook/LocalSystem.html

Check if the DB Store exists too !

Good luck !